# When I submit, a dialog is opened, but refreshing the page closes it

Tags: primefaces, spring-webflow

When I Click on the submit button the flow is launched, it executes the action and I have in this button a parameter onsuccess to open dialog, the problem is the dialog is directly closed om a page refresh.

Comment: please post a piece of your code. Maybe you're making a incorrect update in your button tag

Comment: This question is seriously to broad, vague, unclear etc... See [ask] and create a [mcve].